# How to count values in an XML element using XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, count

I have a set of XML documents that contain some large lists of values in a single XML element.  I need to determine how large each list is and only output the count when they are too large.  I am required to use xsltproc that only supports 1.0 and have tried using the count() function but that does not seem to produce any value other than 1.  An example style-sheet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                >

  <!-- NOTE: US-ASCII encoding is not compatible with Java HTML text -->
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="ASCII"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="'Test Case for count()'"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:element name="table">
          <xsl:attribute name="border">1</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="align">center</xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel" select="'count'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue" select="function-available('count')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel" select="'normalize-space'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue" select="function-available('normalize-space')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel" select="'string-length'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue" select="function-available('string-length')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel" select="'replace'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue" select="function-available('replace')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel" select="'tokenize'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue" select="function-available('tokenize')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel" select="'contains'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue" select="function-available('contains')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:variable name="DataIn" select="' A B C '"/>
          <xsl:variable name="DataList">
            <xsl:call-template name="Tokenize-Str">
              <xsl:with-param name="Data" select="$DataIn"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel"
                            select="concat('tokenize(',$DataIn,')')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue">
              <xsl:call-template name="Tokenize-Str">
                <xsl:with-param name="Data" select="$DataIn"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <xsl:call-template name="DblColTableDataRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="DataLabel"
                            select="concat('count(',$DataIn,')')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="DataValue">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$DataList"/>
              <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(($DataList))"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="DblColTableDataRow">
    <xsl:param name="DataLabel" select="'?:'"/>
    <xsl:param name="DataValue" select="'???'"/>
    <xsl:element name="tr">
      <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">text-align:right</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$DataLabel"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$DataValue"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template needed because tokenize function not supported -->
  <xsl:template name="Tokenize-Str">
    <xsl:param name="Data"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DataStr">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Data)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="0 != string-length($DataStr)">
      <!--xsl:value-of select="concat('Tkn-Str(',$Data,')')"/-->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($DataStr,' ')">
          <xsl:element name="tkn">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DataStr, ' ')"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:call-template name="Tokenize-Str">
            <xsl:with-param name="Data"
                            select="substring-after($DataStr, ' ')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:element name="tkn">
            <xsl:value-of select="$DataStr"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is set up so that the XML document content does not matter.  The command:

```
xsltproc -o tst.html test_case.xsl whatever.xml
```

Produces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ASCII">
<title>Test Case for count()</title></head><body><table border="1" align="center"><tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">count</td>
<td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">normalize-space</td>
<td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">string-length</td>
<td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">replace</td>
<td>false</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">tokenize</td>
<td>false</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">contains</td>
<td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">tokenize( A B C )</td>
<td>
<tkn>A</tkn><tkn>B</tkn><tkn>C</tkn>
</td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td style="text-align:right">count( A B C )</td>
<td>
<tkn>A</tkn><tkn>B</tkn><tkn>C</tkn>: 1</td>
</tr></table></body></html>
```

I am not sure why I am getting a count of 1 since my template is clearly returning 3 element nodes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to count the delimiters?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I thought of that shortly after posting the question.  Unfortunately, my recursion-call in that case is having some sort of parameter passing problem.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. You don't need recursion in order to count the delimiters; it's a simple calculation performed on the input string.

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not know what function I would use to "count delimiters".

Comment: I have posted an answer showing how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to count how many tokens are in a given string, without extracting the individual tokens, you can do so simply by calculating the number of delimiters contained in the string.

Here's a simple example:

**XML**

```
<input>alpha bravo charlie</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <count-tokens>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length(input) - string-length(translate(input, ' ', '')) + 1"/>
    </count-tokens>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<count-tokens>3</count-tokens>
```

Comment: This definately looks like the better way to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

With pure XSLT 1, any variable containing result nodes created with `xsl:element` or literal result elements is a result tree fragment https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments which is a data structure very different from a node-set you get from your input document(s).

So your variable `$DataList` is such a result tree fragment you can output with `xsl:copy-of` but you can't use XPath on its content, for that you need an extension function like `exsl:node-set` (http://exslt.org/exsl/index.html) e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($DataList)/*)" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>` would give you the count you are looking for (as the `exsl:node-set` function converts your result tree fragment into a root node containing your result element nodes).

Note that xsltproc should support http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html, so you should simply be able to use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="count(str:tokenize('A B C', ' '))"/>` with an appropriate namespace declaration of `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"` in your stylesheet.

Comment: Actually, using exslt is what I thought of in the first place.  However, the machine in question is not on-line and I have no way to add such extensions.

Comment: There is no need to "add" support for "exsl:node-set" to "xsltproc". It might be that you have to configure it use "str:tokenize", I can't really tell that although the installation I have on Windows supports it without any configuration. But I don't think anyone creates/installs/configures an XSLT 1 processor without support for `exsl:node-set` (or a corresponding function in a proprietary namespace, as some Microsoft XSLT processor like MSXML or XslTransform do). So use `exsl:node-set`, it has to be supported. Otherwise you would need to run two separate transformation.

Comment: Okay, that works on my test machine out here.  I just need to check it on the isolated machine.